# Tmux how to unbold text in status line

Tags: terminal, tmux

How do I apple a bold style to only a select portion of text within the status line?

Basically, I want to know how to ***un***-bold text after applying a bold style.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `default` or `nobold`:

```
#[bold]TEST#[nobold]
```